# How can I run a script in cmd with an embedded Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

An arbitrary application (say 'ArbApp') supports Python API and Python 3.8.3 is included together when it is installed (embedded Python). But I don't have any method to execute that Python except for opening Python console from the menu of ArbApp as shown below.
[image: Opening Python console in the app]

Because that Python includes some sight-packages required for the app, I need to run some scripts with it **especially in cmd**.
How can I do that?

***Note.***

In ArbApp path, a zipped Python file exists. That's all. Nor does the system environmental variables.
[image: -]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*supports Python API*"?

Comment: Ah sorry, I was meaning ArbApp's API like pyArbApp. So every functions in ArbApp can be called from Python.

Comment: You can make a bat file that will add system environment variables, then run your python script, then remove these environment variables. But it's only you can tell what the environment variables (PATH, mostly, I suppose) should be there. If your embedded python is a zip archive you have to unzip that archive first. It can be done in the same bat file (it will significally slow down a start of your script) or you can do it in advance (probably you could just install the python in advance, it would be simplest solution, actually).

Comment: @YuriKhristich. Thanks. Definitely it is an easy option to do [unzip-add env-run script-remove env] by a bat file. I agree that installing Python externally is the most simplest way but my clients do not accept installing something else except for having a script file :( Thanks again anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Open up cmd and then type in `"python3"` if you have the latest version of Python downloaded. This will open up Python in your command line. To run a specific script, you will have to navigate to the script's file location first, and once you're in it you can type `"python3 [filename]"`, replacing `[filename]` with your python script name, and that will run it for you.

Comment: Sorry. It is not what I need. This is just running Python externally.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. Hopefully you find your answer though!